# The type initializer exception when creating object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting a "The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception." error.  This happens on the line "Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection".

If I open a new project and create this line, it all works??  I am banging my head!!

Comment: Have you successfully set a connection string in your App.config?

Answer (score 0):

Is your line of code only `Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection`? When creating a new `SqlClient.SqlConnection` you need to specify a connection string, like so:

```
Dim cn as New SqlClient.SqlConnection("my connection string here")
```